# Kill Python Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I am running a Python program which uses the multiprocessing module to spawn some worker threads. Using `Pool.map` these digest a list of files.

At some point, I would like to stop everything and have the script die.

Normally `Ctrl+C` from the command line accomplishes this. But, in this instance, I think that just interrupts one of the workers and that a new worker is spawned.

So, I end up running `ps aux | grep -i python` and using `kill -9` on the process ids in question.

Is there a better way to have the interrupt signal bring everything to a grinding halt?

Comment: What are your other threads doing? You can't have a flag in them that you set to false and they quit execution? Is the issue getting the "Ctrl+C" behavior - you could have a useless Tk window pop up and bind a "stop" function to it that sets a kill flag on all of the threads (or a global one). You could even bind a function that executes your terminal kill using Popen, if you're annoyed by having to go to terminal and type that in

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SIGQUIT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) will kill all processes even under Python 2.x.

You can also update to Python 3.x, where this behavior (only child gets the signal) seems to have been fixed.

Comment: *unix continues to surprise and delight me. I was unaware of this command, even after years of explorative usage. Thanks.

Comment: I think the point of the question isn't which signal to use, but rather the fact that sending something like `SIGTERM` will kill the main process but not the children, as discussed by @dano below.

Comment: I came to this question as I had this same issue running Python (3.9) on Windows. For those in the same boat, the appropriate signal there is `CTRL` + `BREAK` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately in Python 2.x there really isn't a good solution for this problem. The best workaround that I know of is to use `pool.map_async(...).get(timeout=<large number>)` instead of `pool.map`. The problem is that `pool.map` makes a call to `threading.Condition.wait()`, which for some reason can't be interrupted by Ctrl+C in Python 2.x (it works in Python 3). When you use `map_async()`, it calls `threading.Condition.wait(timeout=<large number>)`, which ends up doing a busy wait loop, which *can* be interrupted by Ctrl+C.

Try it for yourself:

```
c = threading.Condition()
try:
    c.acquire()
    c.wait()  # You won't be able to interrupt this
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught it")

c = threading.Condition()
try:
    c.acquire()
    c.wait(timeout=100)  # You CAN interrupt this
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Caught it")
```

So, to make your `map` call interruptable, do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    try:
        p.map_async(func, iterable).get(timeout=10000000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Caught it")
        # Optionally try to gracefully shut down the worker processes here.
        p.close()
        # DON'T join the pool. You'll end up hanging.
```

Also note, as pointed out by phihag, this issue is fixed in Python 3.4 (and possibly earlier in 3.x).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways. The first way is to mark the thread as a daemon using

in Threading,

```
myThread.setDaemon(true)
```

in multiprocessing,

```
myThread.daemon = True
```

All threads marked as a daemon will terminate with the main thread. This is not the proper way to do it as it doesn't allow the threads to clean up

The next way is to listen for `KeyboardInterrupt` with a try-catch, and then .join() the threads like such.

```
try:
    myThread = MyThread()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    myThread.join()
```

If your thread is in a loop, you could use a condition such as a boolean, set this to false, and when the condition is false, it performs cleanup.

```
class MyThread(Threading.thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.alive=True
    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            #do stuff
        #cleanup goes here, outside the loop
try:
    myThread = MyThread()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    myThread.alive = False
    myThread.join()
```

Comment: Processes in a `multiprocessing.Pool` are always daemonic, so that isn't helpful here. Trying to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` in the parent process won't help either, because the child processes end up getting KeyboardInterrupt instead of the parent.

Comment: Also, in your third example, setting an attribute on a class from the parent process won't have any affect on the child process, because they'll each get a separate copy of the attribute.

Comment: Ah okay. I've always used threading.Thread so I guess it doesn't carry over. I just sorta assumed they would carry over. You know what happens when you assume...

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the python signal library works pretty well in this case. When you initialize the pool, you can pass a signal handler to each thread to set a default behavior when the main thread gets a keyboard interrupt.

If you really just want everything to die, catch the keyboard interrupt exception in the main thread, and call pool.terminate().

Comment: _If you really just want everything to die, catch the keyboard interrupt exception in the main thread, and call pool.terminate()._  The point is that this doesn't work.